# Radio button selection in asp.net listview

Tags: asp.net, .net, listview, c#-4.0, radio-button

I want use to prevent user to multiple selection in radio button. I'm using the ListView control to bind the radio button in asp.net.

**ListView Design**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvColorName" runat="server" GroupItemCount="2" 
                    GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                    </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="cbColorName" Text='<%# Eval("colorName")%>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

**Out Put**
[image]

I don't want to select multiple. while using normal its happen but not in listview...

Comment: try using `GroupName` if you can use. Otherwise you need to use javascript or jquery for that.

Comment: I tried GroupName but its not happening ? can you suggest javascript code ?

Comment: here is a [similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768323/retrieve-value-for-selected-radiobutton-in-listview-asp-net).

Comment: it's crazy this is still an issue. there are posts about this dating back to 2004!